# memoir: spacing changed in new version

Tags: spacing, memoir

I just updated from memoir 3.6g to 3.6j and it broke spacing in my documents.  In 3.6g, I used:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.6\baselineskip}

\setbeforesecskip{1.5ex}
\setaftersecskip{0.5ex}
\setbeforeparaskip{0.5ex}
```

In 3.6g, this gave me about a line's worth of spacing between `\paragraph` and between `\section` and `\begin{itemize}`.  In 3.6j, the spacing between `\section` and `\begin{itemize}` is the same, but between `\section` and `\paragraph` or two `\paragraph`s is very small.

In order to restore the spacing between `\section` and `\paragraph` or `\paragraph`s in 3.6j, I changed it to:

```
\setbeforesecskip{3ex}
\setaftersecskip{2ex}
\setbeforeparaskip{2.5ex}
```

but now there's too much space (approximately 2 lines) between `\section` and `\begin{itemize}`.  How can I put the spacing back the way it was?

Comment: You might want to report this to the author of the `memoir` class. Such spacing changes classify as bugs as long they are not intentionally.

Comment: They are intentional, non-zero `\parskip` makes spacing around sectional headings hard to control.

Comment: @daleif: Could you extend your comment as an answer?

Comment: Well not really because I can see that the implemenation is flawed, if two sectional macros follow each other they cancel out, so there is some work to be done over easter.

Answer (score 3):

(Based on the comments from [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) [Maintainer of the `memoir` package.])

The modified spacing is intentional, a non-zero `\parskip` makes spacing around sectional headings hard to control. However,  the implementation is flawed: if two sectional macros follow each other they cancel out, so there is some work to be done for a future version.